# OpenCV Sample Code in python

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to get a start on using opencv in python to do some object detection. Are there any example code projects out there?

I've seen some examples that are specific to face detection but they seem to use preprocessed data that I don't know how to generate.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of example codes out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of examples, but I would suggest in any case to give a look at the following sources:

- http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
- http://www.pyimagesearch.com/